# existence of certain prime ideal in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a ring (with identity). Show that if $S$ is a subset of $R$ that is closed under multiplication and does not contain zero, there is some prime ideal $P$ of $R$ that is disjoint from $S$. Show that $R$ always has at least one prime ideal.

> Before I attempt to solve this, I was wondering why the following two definitions of a prime ideal $P$ in a ring $R$ are equivalent:

1. Whenever $a,b \in R$ are such that $aRb \subseteq P,a\in P$ or $b\in P.$
2. Whenever $a,b \in R$ are such that $ab \in  P, a\in P $ or $b \in P.$

It's relatively easy to see why they're equivalent if $R$ is commutative, but I'm not sure how to show $2)\Rightarrow 1)$ for a noncommutative ring.

One may assume that $S$ contains $1$; if not, $S$ can be replaced with $S\cup \{1\}.$ Let $T$ be the set of all ideals disjoint from $S$. $T$ is clearly nonempty as $(0)\in T.$ Then for any chain $\{I_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}, $ where $I_i \subseteq I_{i+1}\,\forall i,$ in $T$, $J := \cup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} I_k$ is in $T$. Indeed, if $s\in J$ for some $s\in S,$ then $s\in I_k$ for some $k$, a contradiction. Thus by Zorn's lemma, $T$ has a maximal element, say $M$. Thus it suffices to show that $M$ is a prime ideal as $S\cap M = \emptyset$.

Since $1\not\in S, 1\not\in M.$ Suppose $a,b\in R$ are such that $ab \in M.$ Suppose $a,b \not\in M.$ Then $M + (a),$ where $(a)$ is the ideal generated by $a$, is strictly larger than $M$ so it intersects $S$. That is, there exists $s\in S$ so that $s = m + ra, m\in M, r\in R.$ Similarly, there exists $s'\in S$ so that $s' = m'+r'b,m'\in M, r'\in R.$ Then $m,m', ab \in M\Rightarrow (ss') = (m+ra)(m'+r'b) = m(m'+r'b)+m'(ra)+rr'(ab)\in M.$ But $ss'\in S$ as $S$ is multiplicatively closed, so $ss'\not\in M$ and hence $M$ is prime.

And finally, $R$ always has at least one prime ideal as we can take $S=\{1\}$ so that we can find a prime ideal of $R$ that is disjoint from $S$ using the above procedure.